# UITableView isn't showing all conten on screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I've a UITableView with 3 sections but the 3rd section not show all content. In this section, I must add items forever, infinitely but the screen not show all content.

My Storyboard:

[image]

How it's working:

[image]

Data Source delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 2 {
            return tableView.rowHeight
        }
        return 44
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                // Section options customer
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellSelectionCreateSale") as! CellSelectionCreateSale

                switch indexPath.row {

                case 0: // Cliente
                    cell.lblField.text = "Cliente"
                    let tapSelectCustomer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlerSelectCustomer))
                    cell.lblOptionSelect.addGestureRecognizer(tapSelectCustomer)
                    break

                case 1: // Main Addr
                    cell.lblField.text = "Endereço Principal"
                    break

                case 2: // Invoice Addr
                    cell.lblField.text = "Endereço de Cobrança"
                    break

                case 3: // Delivery Addr
                    cell.lblField.text = "Endereço de Entrega"
                    break

                    default: break
                }

                return cell
            } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
                // Section options order
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellSelectionCreateSale") as! CellSelectionCreateSale

                switch indexPath.row {

                    case 0: // Create Date
                        cell.lblField.text = "Data do Pedido"
                        // let tapSelectOrderDate = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector())
                        // Sera feito posteriormente

                    case 1: // Expiration Date
                        cell.lblField.text = "Data de Expiração"
                        let tapSelectExpirationDate = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectDateExpiration))
                        cell.lblOptionSelect.addGestureRecognizer(tapSelectExpirationDate)

                    case 2 : // Tipo
                        cell.lblField.text = "Tipo"
                        let tapSelectTipo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlerSelectOpTipo))
                        cell.lblOptionSelect.addGestureRecognizer(tapSelectTipo)
                        break

                    case 3 : // Empresa
                        cell.lblField.text = "Empresa"
                        break

                    case 4:  // Campanha
                        cell.lblField.text = "Campanha"
                        let tapSelectCampaign = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlerSelectOpCampanha(_:)))
                        cell.lblOptionSelect.addGestureRecognizer(tapSelectCampaign)
                        break

                    case 5:  // Price List
                        cell.lblField.text = "Lista de Preço"
                        let tapSelectPriceList = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlerSelectOpPriceList(_:)))
                        cell.lblOptionSelect.addGestureRecognizer(tapSelectPriceList)
                        break

                    case 6:  // Entrega
                        cell.lblField.text = "Entrega"
                        let tapSelectEntrega = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlerSelectOpEntrega(_:)))
                        cell.lblOptionSelect.addGestureRecognizer(tapSelectEntrega)
                        break

                    case 7:  // Pagamento
                        cell.lblField.text = "Pagamento"
                        let tapSelectPgto = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlerSelectOpCondPgto(_:)))
                        cell.lblOptionSelect.addGestureRecognizer(tapSelectPgto)
                        break

                    case 8:  // Due Date
                        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellSelectionCreateSale2") as! CellSelectionCreateSale2
                        let tapDateSelectValidity = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectDateValidity))
                        cell2.lblSelectOption.addGestureRecognizer(tapDateSelectValidity)
                        cell2.txtDias.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textBeginEdit), for: .editingDidBegin)
                        cell2.txtDias.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textEndEdit), for: .editingDidEnd)
                        return cell2

                    default: break
                }

                return cell
            } else {
                let cell = tableViewOrder.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellItemPedido") as! ItemPedidoTableViewCell
                let id_product = itensPedido[indexPath.row].attributes["product_id"] as! Int32
                var name = "[\(SQLite.readField(tabela: "product", campo: "default_code", onde: "id", key: id_product) as! String)]"
                name += " \(SQLite.readField(tabela: "product", campo: "name", onde: "id", key: id_product) as! String)"
                cell.lblName.text = name
                cell.lblDiscount.text = "Margem (%): \((itensPedido[indexPath.row].attributes["discount_list"] as! Double).rounded(toDecimalPlaces: 2))"
                cell.lblQtd.text = "Quantidade: " + String(itensPedido[indexPath.row].attributes["product_uom_qty"] as! Double)
                cell.lblUnitPrice.text = "Preço Unitário: " + Utils.df2so(price: itensPedido[indexPath.row].attributes["price_unit"] as! Double)
                cell.lblPriceList.text = "Lista de Preço: " + Utils.df2so(price: itensPedido[indexPath.row].attributes["price_unit_list"] as! Double)
                cell.lblPriceSubtotal.text = "Subtotal: " + Utils.df2so(price: itensPedido[indexPath.row].attributes["price_subtotal"] as! Double)
                return cell
            }
    }
    // UITableView end
```

In UITableView have 3 types of cells. But just the 3rd section`s cells is the height different.

Comment: Check constraints on your `tableView`. It looks like it doesn't know it's height properly.

Comment: The constraints has been seted like show image 1.

Comment: Are you setting `tableView`'s height somewhere?

Comment: @iPeter yes, on the `Size Inspector` is seted height but not have constraint to set height.

Comment: can you show your tableview delegate datasour methods?

Comment: @iPeter I updated question with that.

Comment: Why have you written `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @iPeter if I don't write this my screen stay: https://ibb.co/eyVjvU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179917/discussion-between-ipeter-and-augusto).